# Axis label dissappear when adding zooming (Vega-Lite)

Tags: zooming, layer, vega-lite

I try to show timeseries data as point charts with two x-axis labels (2 text marks as my main x-axis attribute should not be displayed), mainly one at the top and one at the bottom. This works with a layered approach but as soon as I add the [zoomable parameter](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/selection_translate_scatterplot_drag.html) to the visual, the text mark for the axes labels disappear. Is there a way on how to solve this issue?

That's how the visual looks like - without adding the zooming feature:

[Timeseries point visual with two measure attributes and top and bottom x-axis label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5ues.png)

What I’ve tried so far

- I tried to position the params at different positions in the code as I am also using a vertical rule but it did not work out.
- I also tried to make use of the `scale resolve` but I was neither successful.
- Within the resolve, I tried to make use of the `labelBound` axis information and set it to `false`.

Basically, here is the code that I am currently using

```
{
  "data": {
    "name": "dataset"
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "TIMESTAMP",
      "timeUnit": "utcyearmonthdatehoursminutes",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "axis": {
        "grid": false,
        "title": null,
        "orient": "bottom",
        "labels": false
      }
    }
  },
  "vconcat": [
    {
      "hconcat": [
        {
          "layer": [
            {
              "transform": [
                {
                  "fold": [
                    "ATTRIBUTE1",
                    "ATTRIBUTE2"
                  ],
                  "as": [
                    "measure1",
                    "temp1"
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "mark": {
                "type": "point",
                "filled": true,
                "size": 20
              },
              "height": 150,
              "width": 700,
              "encoding": {
                "x": {
                  "timeUnit": "utcyearmonthdatehoursminutes",
                  "field": "TIMESTAMP",
                  "type": "ordinal",
                  "axis": {
                    "title": null,
                    "labels": false,
                    "ticks": false
                  }
                },
                "y": {
                  "field": "temp1",
                  "type": "quantitative",
                  "axis": {
                    "title": null
                  },
                  "scale": {
                    "zero": false,
                    "domain": [
                      450,
                      490
                    ]
                  }
                },
                "color": {
                  "field": "measure1",
                  "type": "nominal",
                  "legend": {
                    "title": "Measures",
                    "orient": "right"
                  }
                },
                "opacity": {
                  "condition": [
                    {
                      "param": "legendhighlight",
                      "value": 1,
                      "empty": false
                    },
                    {
                      "param": "hover",
                      "value": 1,
                      "empty": false
                    }
                  ],
                  "value": 0.1
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "mark": {
                "type": "text",
                "align": "left",
                "angle": -90,
                "fontSize": 10
              },
              "encoding": {
                "x": {
                  "timeUnit": "utcyearmonthdatehoursminutes",
                  "field": "TIMESTAMP",
                  "type": "ordinal",
                  "axis": {
                    "title": null,
                    "labels": false
                  }
                },
                "text": {
                  "field": "Attribute_TopX"
                },
                "y": {
                  "value": -5
                },
                "color": {
                  "condition": [
                    {
                      "test": "datum['COLORATTRIBUTE']=='COLOR_ITEM1'",
                      "value": "green"
                    },
                    {
                      "test": "datum['COLORATTRIBUTE']=='COLOR_ITEM2'",
                      "value": "steelblue"
                    }
                  ],
                  "value": "black"
                }
              }
            },{
              "mark": {
                "type": "text",
                "align": "right",
                "angle": -90,
                "fontSize": 10
              },
              "encoding": {
                "x": {
                  "timeUnit": "utcyearmonthdatehoursminutes",
                  "field": "TIMESTAMP",
                  "type": "ordinal",
                  "axis": {
                    "title": null,
                    "labels": false
                  }
                },
                "text": {
                  "field": "Attribute_BottomX"
                },
                "y": {
                  "value": "height"
                },
                "color": {
                  "condition": [
                    {
                      "test": "datum['COLORATTRIBUTE']=='COLOR_ITEM1'",
                      "value": "green"
                    },
                    {
                      "test": "datum['COLORATTRIBUTE']=='COLOR_ITEM2'",
                      "value": "steelblue"
                    }
                  ],
                  "value": "black"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "mark": "rule",
              "encoding": {
                "x": {
                  "field": "TIMESTAMP",
                  "type": "temporal"
                },
                "opacity": {
                  "condition": [
                    {
                      "param": "hover",
                      "value": 0.8,
                      "empty": false
                    }
                  ],
                  "value": 0
                },
                "size": {
                  "value": 1
                },
              "params": [
                {
                  "name": "hover",
                  "select": {
                    "type": "point",
                    "encodings": [
                      "x"
                    ],
                    "nearest": true,
                    "on": "mouseover"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "name": "legendhighlight",
                  "select": {
                    "type": "point",
                    "fields": [
                      "measure1"
                    ]
                  },
                  "bind": "legend"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "layer": [
            {
              "transform": [
                {
                  "fold": [
                    "ATTRIBUTE1",
                    "ATTRIBUTE2"
                  ],
                  "as": [
                    "measure1",
                    "temp1"
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "mark": {
                "type": "boxplot"
              },
              "height": 150,
              "width": 100,
              "encoding": {
                "x": {
                  "field": "measure1",
                  "type": "nominal",
                  "axis": {
                    "labels": false,
                    "ticks": false,
                    "title": null
                  }
                },
                "y": {
                  "field": "temp1",
                  "type": "quantitative",
                  "axis": {
                    "labels": false,
                    "ticks": false,
                    "title": null
                  },
                  "scale": {
                    "zero": false
                  }
                },
                "color": {
                  "field": "measure1",
                  "type": "nominal",
                  "legend": null
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "resolve": {
    "scale": {
      "y": "independent",
      "x": "shared",
      "color": "independent"
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the [params code](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/selection_translate_scatterplot_drag.html) that I try to add using Vega-Lite v5:

```
"params": [
                {
                  "name": "grid",
                  "select": "interval",
                  "bind": "scales"
                }
              ],
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you check your provided code ? the curly braces are not properly closed somewhere. Also after enclosing the braces getting error: `Unrecognized signal name: "legendhighlight"`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.